# What is correct answer for this algebraic expression?

Tags: polynomials

If $(x+2)$ and $(x-2)$ are factors of $ax^2+2x-3x^2+bx-4$, then what would be the value of $(a+b)$ from following given options and how to arrive at it?

a) -7

b)  7

c)  14

d)  -8

Comment: Do you know any connection between factors of a polynomial and zeroes of the same polynomial?

Comment: I tried substituting these values of these factores in this expression but some how the answer eludes me.

Comment: None? Your polynomial has to be a multiple of $x^2 - 4$. This gives $a-3 = 1$ and $b+2 = 0$, so $a = 4$, $b = -2$?

Comment: Let me clarify one thong. I have taken it as $ax^2$ since in book it gives as $ax^4$, which I guess is typo error.

Comment: Anyway @user426: with the given info, none of the possibilities matches the actual answer which is $\,a+b=2\,$ , as Martini commented...

Comment: Since the book had $ax^4$, why assume it was a typo? Could the polynomial perhaps have been $ax^4+2x^3-3x^2+bx-4$? In that case answer (a) would be the correct one.

Comment: @RickDecker You are great. Thanks for this input.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Polynomial Division. You could divide the polynomial by $(x+2)$ and $(x-2)$ and add the condition that the rest must be zero hence solve for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Bendjeddo I did proceed in this line but the answer that I get is not tallying with any of the answers in options.

Comment: @user426 in theory it should work , but i didn't try it myself..i'm sorry. But if you were able to find $a$ and $b$ and they didn't match with the solutions maybe you should check your calculations again...

Comment: With the suggestion from Rick Decker, I could get the answer. It was though an error that kept me away from the answer given in the options. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

If $\,\alpha\,,\,\beta\;$ are roots of the quadratic equation $\,ax^2+bx+c=0\;,\;a\neq 0\;$ , then

$$ax^2+bx+c=a(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$$

With the above (or directly if one remembers Vieta's formulae) , we also have, with the same notation, that

$$\begin{align*}\bullet&\;\;\alpha\beta=\frac ca\\\bullet&\;\;\alpha+\beta=-\frac ba\end{align*}$$

Comment: Note that here the sum of the roots, being zero, leads to a particularly straightforward solution.

Comment: Well...yes, @MarkBennet: that is (or was) part of the hint.

Comment: @DonAntonio This method is not covered in their syllabus as I did not find it mentioned in their books. The book explains it the way Amire Bendjeddou explained. Thanks for the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $ $ by the  Factor Theorem, the roots $\,x = 2,\,-2,\,$ yield factors $\,x\!-\!2,\,x\!+\!2,\,$ so

$$ (a\!-\!3)\, x^2 + (b\!+\!2)\, x - 4\, =\, c\,(x\!-\!2)(x\!+\!2)\, =\, c\,x^2 -4\,c $$

Comparing coefficients $\ {-}4 = -4c,\ \ b\!+\!2 = 0,\ a\!-\!3 = c,\ $ so $\ c,b,a\, =\,\ldots$

Alternatively, evaluate at $\,x = \pm 2,\,$ then solve the two equations for $\, a,b.$